How to modify a JCL variable inside a JCL procedure then use it in another step or another procedure
A procedure that has one step is used several times in a job, it is necessary that this step is executed only once in the whole job and the rest of the places are flushed.
also I don't want to change the JOB MAXCC, so I can't use COND for the procedure step.
I tried to control this with a variable, but the value of the variable that is set inside the procedure does not affect outside the procedure and in the job and subsequent procedures.
I've try this:
JOB:
//   SET DONE=0
//   EXEC MYPROC
//   EXEC MYPROC 
...

Procedure
//MYPROC PROC
//       IF (&DONE=0) THEN
//        EXEC PGM=MYPROG
//        SET DONE=1
//       ENDIF

I'm expecting that the value of variable changed, but it's not.

You can't do this, as far as I'm aware.  Are you open to other solutions?

You say the step with that procedure should be executed only once yet occurs several times in the job - what determines which proc is executed?

You example with the SET, EXEC, EXEC makes no sense - why would you do this in a real environment? What's the difference between the 2 'EXEC MYPROC' steps? Is this a homework problem? Is this an X-Y problem (you think that 'Y' (your question) is the solution to the problem you have (X), but if you told use what X is (the actual problem you are trying to solve) we might be able to come up with a different solution

I don't see a way for a PROC to change the value of a JCL variable in
the parent.
See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=symbols-using-in-nested-procedures

Traditionally variables went in to Proc's and where not passed back (my knowledge is from 15 years ago).
For people from a Unix/Linux background, I would describe JCL as operating below the level of the Shell. You use JCL to start a TSO session. When you logon to Two, you might get the option of specifying a PROC. The PROC is a JCL procedure.

You can accomplish what you are trying using a File.
Options include

IDCAM's step with a REPRO INDATASET(...) OUTFILE(OUT01) will give a
rc=4/8 if the dataset does not exist.

//TEST   PGM=IDCAMS
//* Add the ads for IDCAMS e.g. sysprint
//SYSIN  DD *
   REPRO INDATASET(my.test.dataset) OUTFILE(OUT01)
//OUT01  DD SYSOUT=*


Use a Rexx program/file
Use a Special program for these sort of tests.

At One Site we had program that stored variables as a line in a sequential file. The first 12 characters of the line. The program could update a value or test a variable for a value.

If the job contains multiple steps executing that PROC, yet you only want the proc to execute once, the the first occurrence of that proc will need a COND statement based upon one of the preceding steps that determines if it should run.
Subsequent occurrences  of that step should have a COND statements referring to the previous occurrence that cause the step to not run if the previous one did run and vice-versa.
Alternatively you can break the job into multiple steps and use your scheduling software to control execution to achieve the same result.
I know you said you don't want to use MAXCC and that you think this means you can't use COND, but we don't really have enough detail to determine this.
